# Random Forest with train AUC = 1 and test AUC = 58%

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, scikit-learn, roc, overfitting

I'm trying to understand why my train AUC = 1 while my test AUC is near 58% using random forest.

- **Context**: You are trying to sell a product, and you have historic data about the purchases/noPurchases of such product, from March 2020 to August 2020. You leave August for test data, and the rest for training data. It results approximately in 80% train and 20% test. Each purchase/noPurchase is related to one client, and the data available for that client is the month before the purchase. For example: If a client purchase/noPurchase on July, the data available for that client in that month is June.
- **Data** (train+test): 75 columns and 10k rows, target variable is binary with 90%-10% imbalance. All data is numeric.
- **Modeling**: The scoring is ROC_AUC, and all predictions should be probabilities (to plot roc curve)

**Code**: `train = X_train + y_train`; `test = X_test + y_test`

```
# STANDARDIZE AND IMPUTE TRAIN AND TEST SEPARATED
scaler = StandardScaler()
imputer = KNNImputer()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_train_scaled = imputer.fit_transform(X_train_scaled)
X_test_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_test)
X_test_scaled = imputer.fit_transform(X_test_scaled)

# MODEL
model = RandomForestClassifier() # we instantiate the model
model.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train) # fit
y_train_predictions = model.predict_proba(X_train_scaled) # predict

# EXTRACT TRAIN CLASSES TO PLOT
for i,k in enumerate(model.classes_ == 1):
    print(i,k)
    if k == True:
        y_train_predictions = y_train_predictions[:,i]
y_test_predictions = model.predict_proba(X_test_scaled) # predict

# EXTRACT TEST CLASSES TO PLOT
for i,k in enumerate(model.classes_ == 1):
    print(i,k)
    if k == True:
        y_test_predictions = y_test_predictions[:,i]

# PLOT
fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_train, y_train_predictions)
plt.plot(fpr, tpr)
fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_test, y_test_predictions)
plt.plot(fpr, tpr)
```

[image]

And the problem is that `train AUC = 1` and `test AUC = 58%` approx. I thought on these possible causes:

- The dependent variable is included in the `X_train` matrix. (Checked, it isn't)
- There is some explanatory variable (e.g. credit card charges of the product, if I have credit card charges data) that is included in `X_train`

However, I discard both possible causes above because I checked meticulously the first one, and the second one is not possible given that the maximum feature importance is `0.0429`

But still, is there any other possible explanation for `train AUC = 1` and `test AUC = 58%`, or something I'm missing?

PS: [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/333199/random-forest-has-almost-perfect-training-auc-compared-to-other-models) is a very similar question, but all the answers are general given that the OP doesn't specify how is building the model (that's why I put all the code)

Comment: You are saying using two separate scalers and imputers is misleading, but you also say that test data should be scaled/imputed using a separated scaler ("test data should be scaled/imputed using test data scaler"), which is what I just did. On another point, why there is data leakage if you use separated scalers/imputers?

Comment: Sorry, typo! My bad.
Using two separate scalers (and imputers) one for the training and one of the test data is misleading. Test data should be scaled/imputed using the *train* data scaler otherwise there is leakage. Regularise more; for example, increase the minimum number of instances per leaf and/or reduced the maximum tree depth. Leakage will exist because we do not know beforehand  anything about the mean or variance of our test data. Think the scenario we have a single test point, what would be the variance then?